# What is the SQL Server syntax to sum sales for s certain day using a stored procedure parameter for date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

Here's my table definition:

**tblTrans**

```
PK - trans_id (int)
   - user_id_fk (int)
   - trans_created (datetime)
   - trans_amount (money)
```

I want to sum all sales data for a given day, and return it as `NumberOfTransactions,TotalDollars`

I have the following SQL query that I want to move to a stored procedure that takes `MM/DD/YYYY` as a parameter.

The query works, I'm just not sure how to pass in the parameter.

```
SELECT Cast(count(*) as varchar(8)) + ','
                         +  Cast(Sum(trans_amount) as varchar(8)) as SalesData 
FROM PD_Transaction 
WHERE pd_Trans_CreatedOn BETWEEN '20130122' 00:00:00.000' AND '20130122 23:59:59.997'
```

I want to create this as a stored procedure, and pass in just the date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If passing one date only:

```
CREATE PROC P @Date DATE
AS BEGIN 
    SELECT Cast(count(*) as varchar(8)) + ',' +  Cast(Sum(trans_amount) as varchar(8)) as SalesData FROM PD_Transaction WHERE pd_Trans_CreatedOn
    BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 121) + ' 00:00:00', 121) and CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 121) + ' 23:59:59', 121)
END
```

Comment: That's the part I was struggling with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I quess you using SQL Server as RDBMS from your query.
Here is the stored proc :

```
CREATE PROC P @startDate DATE, @endDate DATE
AS BEGIN 
    SELECT Cast(count(*) as varchar(8)) + ',' +  Cast(Sum(trans_amount) as varchar(8)) as SalesData FROM PD_Transaction WHERE pd_Trans_CreatedOn
    BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
END
```

Comment: I think I feel stupid right this second.... I may have been over thinking this... the 24 hour time format was messing me up. I guess I need to play with it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare two parameters in the sproc, @StartDate and @EndDate etc.
In your code, assign the parameter with

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2013,01,22);
DateTime dtEnd= new DateTime(2013,01,23);
```

Then the sql script will be something like

```
*.....FROM PD_Transaction WHERE pd_Trans_CreatedOn >= @StartDate AND pd_Trans_CreatedOn < @EndDate*
```